# Best way of doing form validation in React Js

Tags: reactjs

In angular2, if we want to implement form validation we will use Directives.
In React, how can we achieve this validations ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React js form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755214/react-js-form-validation)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:

1. Create your own validation from scratch with plain javascript
2. Use browser APIs
3. Or you can use 3rd party plugins like 'ract-validation': https://github.com/Lesha-spr/react-validation

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with too many libraries on web, here is the one I have found more helpful in entire react world. It can make developers more productive by simplifying validation job.

**Try using :** [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik)

```
npm install formik --save
```

> **Why you should use :**
>   It will saves you writing too much boggy JSX (involving annoying
>   properties) and dealing directly with underline handling (writing own
>   `onBlur()` `onChange()` event handlers) just to achieve
>   validation.

Formik is a small library that helps you with the 3 most annoying parts:

- Getting values in and out of form state
- Validation and error messages
- Handling form submission

By colocating all of the above in one place, Formik will keep things organized--making testing, refactoring, and reasoning about your forms a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Formik. 
I am currently working with it in a project and it goes quite well.

As per their readme.md in github they say: 
"Formik is a small library that helps you with the 3 most annoying parts:

Getting values in and out of form state
Validation and error messages
Handling form submission
By colocating all of the above in one place, Formik will keep things organized--making testing, refactoring, and reasoning about your forms a breeze."